# What's the best way to display on a browser running on a computer/tablet/cell a video stored on my IIS server

Tags: c#, iis, video-streaming, html5-video

I storing some videos on my IIS server and would like to now display them on a browser. I'm aware that HTML5 has a video tag, but don't know how many browsers can use that. I'm also open to use a 3rd party tool (if needed).

The videos will need to display on the major browsers running on a computer, tablets and cellphones.

Sorry, one last point.
The videos are currently encoded as h264 and their size are between 50k and 200k.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all major browsers support the html5 video element at this point. There's a matrix available on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/video).

The only browsers of note that don't support it are IE8 and Opera Mini, which is a pretty short list.

Comment: Cool, I'll check on that.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to streaming video, I always recommend distributing the video via Vimeo, it's super easy, and the player can be customised to a degree.  Streaming the video on your own server just sucks up your bandwidth. Vimeo can take away all those network/mime type issues, they'll even deliver a customised experience depending on your browser, you'd have to do all that yourself if you were delivering it via your own website.

Comment: Do they have an API for uploading the videos? My videos are 50 to 200K max.